# PHP Form not working IE and Chrome, but fine in FF

Tags: php, forms, internet-explorer, google-chrome

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['accountUser']) && isset($_POST['accountPassword'])) {
    include("dbase.php");
    include("settings.php");

    if ($_POST['accountType']=="member") {
        $database="chatusers";
    } else if ($_POST['accountType']=="model") {
        $database="chatmodels";
    } else if ($_POST['accountType']=="studioop") {
        $database="chatoperators";
    }

    $userExists=false;
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,user,password,status FROM $database WHERE status!='pending' AND status!='rejected' ");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $tempUser=$row["user"];
        $tempPass=$row["password"];
        $tempId=$row["id"];     

        if ($_POST['accountUser']==$tempUser && md5($_POST['accountPassword'])==$tempPass) {
            if ($row["status"]=="blocked") {
                $userExists=true;
                $errorMsg="Account is blocked, please contact the administrator for more details";
            } else {        
                $userExists=true;
            $currentTime=time();
            mysql_query("UPDATE $database SET lastLogIn='$currentTime' WHERE id = '$tempId' LIMIT 1");
            setcookie("usertype", $database, time()+3600);
            setcookie("id", $tempId, time()+3600);
            header("Location: cp/$database/");
            }
        }
    }

    if (!$userExists){
        $errorMsg="Wrong Username or password";
    }

} else if (isset($_GET['from']) && $_GET['from']=="recoverpass"){
    $errorMsg="Your new password has been sent to your mail";
} else {
    $errorMsg="Please complete username and password fields";
}
?>

<?
include("_main.header.php");
?>

<table width="720" height="200" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

  <tr>

    <td align="center" valign="middle"><form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="form1">

      <p>&nbsp;</p>

      <table width="720" border="0" align="center">

        <tr>

          <td colspan="2"><p align="left">

              <span class="error"><?php if ( isset($errorMsg) && $errorMsg!=""){ echo $errorMsg; } ?></span>

              <br>

              <br>

</p></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

          <td width="210" align="right" valign="top" class="form_definitions"><div align="right">Username:</div></td>

          <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="accountUser" type="text" id="accountUser" value="<? echo $_GET[user];?>" size="24" maxlength="24"></td>

          </tr>

        <tr>

          <td align="right" valign="top" class="form_definitions"><div align="right">Password:</div></td>

          <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="accountPassword" type="password" id="accountPassword2" size="24" maxlength="24"></td>

          </tr>

        <tr>

          <td align="right" valign="top" class="form_definitions"><div align="right">Account type:</div></td>

          <td align="left" valign="top">

              <select name="accountType" id="select">

                <option value="member" selected>Member</option>

                <option value="model">Model</option>

                <option value="studioop">Studio Operator</option>

              </select>            <div align="left"></div></td>

          </tr>

        <tr>

          <td align="right" valign="top" class="form_definitions">&nbsp;</td>

          <td align="left" valign="top">

            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Log In to your account">            <div align="left"></div></td>

          </tr>

        <tr>

          <td align="right" valign="top" class="form_definitions">&nbsp;</td>

          <td align="left" valign="top"><a href="lostpassword.php" class="left">Lost Password? Press Here!</a></td>

          </tr>

      </table>

    </form></td>

  </tr>

</table>

<br>

<br>

<?
include("_main.footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: can you edit the source code properly?

Comment: This should have nothing to do with PHP, so perhaps you can post the form HTML from a View Page Source.

Comment: If you add print_r($_POST); on top the form what does it print ut after posting in IE or chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are missing a quote in the html you didn't post here.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome fails on `&nbsp` in td cells.

```
<td align="right" valign="top" class="form_definitions">&nbsp;</td>
```

Should just be

```
<td align="right" valign="top" class="form_definitions"></td>
```

This took me forever to figure out